# How can i call a function in Angular in a reactive form

Tags: angular

I have a form element in my reactive form like below

```
 <form [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit)="handleClick()">
```

which works fine when i hit the submit bttn, but i have another bttn on the form from which i want to call a different function. I searched and could not find something that works. i tried something like this

```
 <button  ng-click=”newClick()” type=”button” class="btn survey-reset-btn">Get Info</button>
```

or

```
<button (click)=”newClick($event)” type=”button”>Button</button>
```

but that creates me an error and complains about the () around click.

sow how can i have bttn on my form which dont call the same function ?

Comment: Please share the implementation for `newClick`. `(click)="newClick($event)"` would be exactly how it is done, assuming `newClick` is implemented in the component class code. Also, it may just be a formatting thing, but I'm seeing two different types of quotes in your code `"` and `”`, which could cause parsing issues.

Comment: as @AlexanderStaroselsky said if you could share your code then it can be checked . (click) syntax looks okay. One the thing I am curious to see is the quotation marks in this case. Those look different than you have for "form". On button it looks like it might be something else than expected "

Comment: You're asking us about an error, but don't post the error. That's really not a good strategy. I would guess that the problem is caused by your usage of smart quotes (`”`) rather than regular quotes (`"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be the issue of quote symbol. Replace `”` with `"`.

> `<button (click)="newClick($event)" type="button">Button</button>`